# Python crashing on loading pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have pygame and numpy installed and both seem to be working on win10
from python shell:

```
import pygame
```

(working)

put in a script:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import * 
pygame.init() 
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')  
while True: # main game loop  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Pygame window opens and python stops. Before I exit out of python says in the python shell "no module named pygame"

Comment: Did you check which version of python your shell is using, compared to which python is your system default?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install with pip. From the command line type:

```
pip install pygame
```

Comment: Check that `pip` is installing to the Python3 environment and not Python2. `pip3` would be a better choice